# Use :after to add keyline after text that spans the rest of the element area

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a keyline to a description list `DT` element.

The idea is the keyline follows the text in the `DT` element which leads your eye to the `DD` element.

See my design below...

[image]

I thought it would be easy to do using `:after` but I'm perplexed in how to make it work now.

See the code below, if anyone can share their wisdom that would be awesome.

JSfiddle here too https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/x4ua3epm/

```css
@import 'http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,500,600,700');

BODY {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
}

DT {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05rem;
}

DT:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #b6b6b6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <dl class="row mt-3 mb-3">

    <dt class="col-4">Foreword</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">Carmelo Ezpeleta – CEO Dorna Sports</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">The Season</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">An overview by Mat Oxley</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">Technical Review</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">Mat Oxley</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">The Bikes</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">A two-page focus on each of the bikes from Aprilia, Ducati, Honda, KTM, Suzuki, and Yamaha</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">The Riders</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">A detailed account of each rider’s season</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">The Races</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">Eight-pages per MotoGP round report including detailed results data</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">Moto2</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">A five-page season round-up</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">Moto3</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">A five-page season round-up</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">Red Bull Rookies Cup</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">The season in review</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">Two Wheels for Life</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">Update on the year</dd>

    <dt class="col-4">Champions</dt>
    <dd class="col-8">A history of Grand Prix Champions</dd>

  </dl>

</div>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your css with the code below and worked for me

```
DT {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05rem;
  overflow: hidden; // new property

  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block; //changed from block to inline-block
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #b6b6b6;
    margin-top: 10px; //for top spacing 
    margin-left: 5px; //for left spacing
  }

}
```

Let me know if it helps,

Comment: Perfect, why didn't I think of that lol. Dude thanks a lot! Appreciate the help.